# draw the depth value in opengl using shaders

Tags: opengl, shader

I want to draw the depth buffer in the fragment shader, I do this:

**Vertex shader:**

```
varying vec4 position_;

gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
position_ = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
float depth = ((position_.z / position_.w) + 1.0) * 0.5;

gl_FragColor = vec4(depth, depth, depth, 1.0);
```

But all I print is white, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd like to see a bit more context; the shaders instructions as they are look good to me. What color do you specify to your vertices? The only thing I can think of is, that the shader is not fully loaded and you're running the default fixed pipeline settings, which incidently draw write primitives. For debugging set glColor3f(1,0,0); in your main program and gl_FragColor = vec4(0, depth, 0, 1.0); in the shader so tell fixed function and shader pipeline apart.

Comment: I did some debugging in the gDebugger and my code was right, the reason everything was white was that the depth values were very close to one, 0.999, 0.98888. the gl_fragcolor set the color to 256 in the texture

Comment: This is to be expected in a perspective projection situation, due to the nonlinear distribution of depth values. See @Nicol Bolas' answer.

Comment: Thinking about it, those values indicate a suboptimal choice for near and far clipping plane distance. Ideally near and far clip plane "touch" the scene, i.e. the near clip plane is as far in as possible and the the far clip plane as close as possible. If your clip planes were set like this you should see at least some depth values closer to 0.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In what space do you want to draw the depth? If you want to draw the window-space depth, you can do this:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.z);
```

However, this will not be particularly useful, since most of the numbers will be very close to 1.0. Only extremely close objects will be visible. This is the nature of the distribution of depth values for a depth buffer using a standard perspective projection.

Or, to put it another way, that's why you're getting white.

If you want these values in a linear space, you will need to do something like the following:

```
float ndcDepth = ndcPos.z =
    (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.z - gl_DepthRange.near - gl_DepthRange.far) /
    (gl_DepthRange.far - gl_DepthRange.near);
float clipDepth = ndcDepth / gl_FragCoord.w;
gl_FragColor = vec4((clipDepth * 0.5) + 0.5);
```

Comment: gl_FragColor = vec4(...) will also set the alpha value to the depth value. It's unlikely you'd want to blend depth fragments, but placing depth in the alpha channel is a bit unusual.

Comment: Also wouldn't it be easier (to implement and on the GPU) to determine the depth in relation to the depth range in eye space? It interpolates linear and thus save some instructions in the fragment stage.

Comment: @datenwolf The clip-space Z is just a linear transformation of the eye-space Z. And since we're talking about rendering to an image that you can look at, there would be no difference between mapping the clip-space Z to [0, 1] and mapping the eye-space Z to [0, 1].

Comment: Either way, doing it in the vertex shader, I say, is the elegant solution.

Answer (score 16):

Indeed, the "depth" value of a fragment can be read from it's *z* value in clip space (that is, after all matrix transformations).  That much is correct.

However, your problem is in the division by `w`.
Division by `w` is called *perspective divide*.  Yes, it is necessary for perspective projection to work correctly.

**However**.  Division by `w` in this case "bunches up" all your values (as you have seen), to being very close to 1.0.  There is a good reason for this:  in a [perspective projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb281727(v=vs.85).aspx), `w= (some multiplier) *z`.  That is, you are dividing the z value (whatever it was computed out to be) by the (some factor of) original z.  No wonder you always get values near 1.0.  You're almost dividing z by itself.

As a very simple fix for this, try dividing `z` just by the farPlane, and send that to the fragment shader as *depth*.

Vertex shader

```
varying float DEPTH ;

uniform float FARPLANE ;  // send this in as a uniform to the shader

gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
DEPTH = gl_Position.z / FARPLANE ; // do not divide by w
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying float DEPTH ;
// far things appear white, near things black
gl_Color.rgb=vec3(DEPTH,DEPTH,DEPTH) ;
```

The result is a not-bad, very linear-looking fade.

[image]