# My openGL render depths are nearly the value of 1 why is that?

Tags: opengl, glsl, depth, depth-buffer, depth-testing

I do some basic stuff

1) calculate my position
2) store it into "gl_Position"
3) then i store my depth into a vec2 based on my position info

```
gl_Position = vec4( vVertexPos, 1 ) * mMVP;
vDepth = gl_Position.zw;
```

vDepth is a variable above in my shader that i pass to my fragment shader

```
out vec2 vDepth;
```

in the fragment shader i store the fragment depth in gl_FragDepth

```
gl_FragDepth = vDepth.x / vDepth.y;
```

my depth values are all near the value of 1.
Am I doing something incorrect? 
Might I be missing a step that will give me my linear depth values?
when i calculate my camera info my near clipping is 0.01 and my far clipping is 200.0f i need the near to be around that clipping space.

Comment: my normal rendering process stuff works just fine. I out put models no problem. I'm wondering what I might be missing to make my depths look more gradient.

Answer (score 4):

The [closer the near plane is to the viewer](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/love_your_z_buffer.html), the faster your depth buffer precision gets used closer to the viewer. Pushing your near plane out from the eye, but leaving the same distance to your far plane will even out your depth precision throughout your view volume. Your vDepth is also being interpolated in a [perspective-correct method](http://www.geeks3d.com/20130514/opengl-interpolation-qualifiers-glsl-tutorial/) according to 1/w.

Comment: if i change my near plane out to my far plane won't I just stop near clipping properly at that point?

Comment: If your near plane was equal to your far plane, then yes but that's not what I'm saying. What I'm saying is assuming (far - near) is constant, the closer near is to the eye, the less precision you have throughout the rest of your depths.  Some of this is due to the Z-buffer not being linear and also that if there isn't anything close to the eye which might be clipped by the near plane, you are just wasting precision in the depth buffer anyways. Long story short, if it won't clip anything close to the eye, push out your near plane.

Comment: Ok the precision part makes sense. Keep my precision where needed. I figure I have to go edit my values more properly in my shader kind of like how the article how

http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut13%20Deceit%20in%20Depth.html

states?

Comment: I'd say that most of the time you shouldn't be modifying your Z-depths yourself and if you are, you should have a really good reason for it. The tutorial you referenced modifies Z-depths because it is drawing imposters, textured 2D sprites simulating real geometry, and is modifying Z-depths so the written Z-depth is that of the simulated geometry and not the sprite being drawn.

Comment: well i need my depths for deferred rendering if i leave it alone my depths are just all those 0.9999 close values. so I would like to store them all properly. hopefully to get an image like this.

Image off google:
http://fd.fabiensanglard.net/quake2/depthBeforeEntities.jpg

Comment: OpenGL already calculates depth as z/w as part of perspective divide, so you are doing exactly what OpenGL does by default.

Comment: ok so then i would need to do something like

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408851/draw-the-depth-value-in-opengl-using-shaders

specified in Answer2 of that article? 

Its the only calculation I have not tried.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set `gl_FragDepth` in the fragment shader unless you want something other than the default behavior (ie, `gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z`)

See: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut13%20Deceit%20in%20Depth.html for why this is bad for perf.

Comment: ok so basically either i set clipping data with glDepthRange and manipulate the variables because openGL stored them for me. Or pass the near and far clipping data to my shader for calculating. correct?