# Depth Map is white - webgl

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am using the shaders to draw the depth map in my image.
Here is my shader code :

vertex shader:

```
void main(void) {
        gl_PointSize = aPointSize;
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vColor = aVertexColor;
        visdepth = aisdepth;
        vHasTexture = aHasTexture;
        if (aHasTexture > 0.5)
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

    }
```

Fragement Shader:

```
void main(void) {
        if (vHasTexture < 0.5 && visdepth < 0.5)
            gl_FragColor = vColor;

        if (vHasTexture > 0.5) {    

            vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTexture, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, textureColor.a * uTextureAlpha);
        }
        if (visdepth > 0.5){

            float ndcDepth = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.z - gl_DepthRange.near - gl_DepthRange.far) /
                            (gl_DepthRange.far - gl_DepthRange.near);
            float clipDepth = ndcDepth /gl_FragCoord.w;

            gl_FragColor = vec4((clipDepth*0.5)+0.5);
        }   
    }
```

I used the following link as reference for my calculations : [draw the depth value in opengl using shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408851/draw-the-depth-value-in-opengl-using-shaders)

I am getting all my values to be white as shown below:

[image]

[image]

From the two images above, it is clearly seen that points to the far right of the image are behind. This is not reflected in the image I downloaded. After using drawArrays function, I use the toDataUrl function to download the canvas data. The images are a result of the download. Does anyone know of any possible reasons for this?

Comment: what is your camera far value?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the distance between near- and far clipping plane?

Comment: I am not sure how to find the value or where it should be set

Comment: so how can I help you then? it is your application.

Comment: I did not know that it could be happening because of the far value. so it was definitely helpful cause I know where to look now.

Answer (score 2):

for anyone who seeks an answer to that question , here's a little hint :
if you want to view the depth map , you have to linearize it...

```
float linearize_Z(float depth , float zNear , float zFar){

return (2*zNear ) / (zFar + zNear - depth*(zFar -zNear)) ;
}
```

Comment: Where does this formula come from?

Comment: @Makogan hello , everything is explained in that link, in ... depth ;) https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing